# How to find and save parallel shortest path in undirected graph by Dijkstra’s algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, path

I have the follow graph:

```
A-B,11
A-C,10
B-D,5
C-D,6
C-E,15
D-E,4
```

The task is to find shortest path, print route and distance to all pairs like this:

```
Path: A -> D
Route: A -> C -> D
Distance: 10 + 6 = 16
```

In that example of graph, we have few path that repeating, but have a various route, like this:

```
Route: A -> B -> D
Route: A -> C -> D
```

I need to save all of this various path and print at the end. Now program find and print all path exept these cases. I tried many options, but for some reason I can’t understand how to solve this problem.
I store weights in 2 dimentional array like this:

```
    A    B    C    D    E
A   0   11   10    0    0
B  11    0    0    5    0
C  10    0    0    6   15
D   0    5    6    0    4
E   0    0   15    4    0
```

My code below:

```
...
typedef struct s_way_dijkstra {
    int isld_nm;
    bool is_chk;
    int parent;
    struct s_way_dijkstra *next;
}t_way_dijkstra;

void printDistance(t_way_dijkstra *djk_var, int j) {
    if (djk_var[j].parent == -1 )
        return;

    printDistance(djk_var, djk_var[j].parent);   
    if (djk_var[j].parent != 0 ) 
    printstr("+ ");
    printint(djk_var[j].isld_nm - djk_var[djk_var[j].parent].isld_nm); 
    printstr(" ");

    // for (;i > 0 && djk_var->parent[i] != -1; i--)
        // printf("%d ", j);
}

void printRoute(t_way_dijkstra *djk_var, int j, char **isld) {
    if (djk_var[j].parent == -1)
        return;

    printRoute(djk_var, djk_var[j].parent, isld); 
    printstr(" -> ");
    printstr(isld[j]); 
}

static void printSolution(t_way_dijkstra *djk_var, int n, char **isld, int src) {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", djk_var[i].isld_nm);
    printf("\n");

    printf("\nparent\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", djk_var[i].parent);
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = src; i < n; i++) {
        if (djk_var[i].isld_nm != 0) {
            // Path
            printstr("Path: ");
            printstr(isld[src]);
            printstr(" -> ");
            printstr(isld[i]);

            // Route
            printstr("\nRoute: ");
            printstr(isld[src]);
            printRoute(djk_var, i, isld);
            printstr("\n");

            // Distance
            if (djk_var[i].parent >= 1) {
            printstr("Distance: ");
            printDistance(djk_var, i);
            printstr("= ");
            printint(djk_var[i].isld_nm);
            printstr("\n");
            }
            else {
                printstr("Distance: ");
                printint(djk_var[i].isld_nm);
                printstr("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

static int get_min_distance(t_way_dijkstra *djk_var , t_main *vars) {
    int min_val = INT_MAX;
    int min_ind = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vars->nmb_isld; i++) {
        if (djk_var[i].is_chk == false && djk_var[i].isld_nm <= min_val) {
            min_val = djk_var[i].isld_nm;
            min_ind = i;
        }       
    }
    return min_ind;
}

static void dijkstra(int src, t_main *vars, t_graph *graph, t_way_dijkstra *djk_var) {
    int min_ind = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vars->nmb_isld; i++) {
        djk_var[i].parent = -1;
        djk_var[i].isld_nm = INT_MAX;
        djk_var[i].is_chk = false;
    }
    djk_var[src].isld_nm = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vars->nmb_isld; i++) {
        min_ind = get_min_distance(djk_var, vars);
        djk_var[min_ind].is_chk = true;
        for (int j = src; j < vars->nmb_isld; j++) {
            if (!djk_var[j].is_chk && graph->array[min_ind][j] 
            && djk_var[min_ind].isld_nm != INT_MAX
            && djk_var[min_ind].isld_nm + graph->array[min_ind][j] < djk_var[j].isld_nm) {  
                djk_var[j].parent = min_ind;
                djk_var[j].isld_nm = djk_var[min_ind].isld_nm + graph->array[min_ind][j];

            }
        }

    }

    printSolution(djk_var, vars->nmb_isld, graph->isld, src);
}
...
```

Comment: If you want a *C* answer (as your title implies), why do you tag the question "C++" and "C++11" etc? C and C++ are *very different* languages.

Comment: What is your question? I think this is not programming language specific.

Comment: I tried to read the code, seems like something is missing, where and how do you load the graph distances.

Comment: @BobRun the struct graph contains an 2 dimentional arr "array", it stores the weight to all nodes. I added these things to the question.

Comment: @TomKuschel I need to store and output both paths 
`Route: A -> B -> D 
Route: A -> C -> D`

Comment: No you didn't, you added function get_min_distance() to the code, but this has  nothing to do with loading graph distances, people want to help you but you make it very difficult.

Comment: @BobRun I wrote in what form are stored ways and in which variable. What exactly you don't understand?